# Why the elements in the queue are the same

Tags: java, queue

In the project I was responsible for the mail sending function, but in the use of the queue when there is a problem.

```
private void createReportEmail()
{
    try
    {
        List<Map> list = emailMapper.getToAddress();
        System.out.println(list);
        MailSenderInfo mailSenderInfo = new MailSenderInfo();
        mailSenderInfo = CreateEmailService.sendReportMail(emailMapper);
        InternetAddress address = new InternetAddress();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
        {
            if (list.get(i).get("address").toString() != null && list.get(i).get("address").toString() != "")
                address = new InternetAddress(list.get(i).get("address").toString());
            MailSenderInfo mailSenderInfo2 = new MailSenderInfo();
            mailSenderInfo2 = mailSenderInfo;
            mailSenderInfo2.setAddress(address);
            queue.offer(mailSenderInfo2);
        }
        for(int i =0;i<list.size();++i)
        {
            System.out.println(queue.poll().getAddress());
        }

    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now I'm sure the elements in the List are different from each other, but all that's stored in the queue is the content of the last element of the list.I want to know why

Comment: why don't u use `StringUtils.isBlank()` class against the `(list.get(i).get("address").toString() != null && list.get(i).get("address").toString() != "")` . 
it will check both of the condition in a single method `isBlank()`. Thank You :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a new `MailSenderInfo` instance in each iteration of the loop, which is the correct thing to do, but then you replace it with an existing `MailSenderInfo` instance (created before the loop in - `MailSenderInfo mailSenderInfo = new MailSenderInfo();`), so you always add the same `MailSenderInfo` instance to the queue:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) { 
        ...
        MailSenderInfo mailSenderInfo2 = new MailSenderInfo();
        mailSenderInfo2 = mailSenderInfo; // remove this
        mailSenderInfo2.setAddress(address);
        queue.offer(mailSenderInfo2);
    }
```

Comment: yes,but i change its'address',when i print  'address',i found all of them are the same.

Comment: @Vayne It doesn't matter. If you add the same object multiple times into the queue, calling `mailSenderInfo2.setAddress(address)` changes the address of all the elements of the queue.

Comment: yeah,maybe i know why.The queue is stored in the pointer,what i  changed is  the only   object,and all of elements(pointer) point to the same object.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest another change in `if` block with `StringUtils`

```
if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(list.get(i).get("address").toString()))
      address = new InternetAddress(list.get(i).get("address").toString());
      MailSenderInfo mailSenderInfo2 = new MailSenderInfo();
      mailSenderInfo2.setAddress(address);
      queue.offer(mailSenderInfo2);
```

and remove the line `mailSenderInfo2 = mailSenderInfo;`. because `mailSenderInfo` which contains the older object reference.

Comment: good idea.Thank you!!!